# What is the easiest way to move angular1 app to angular2 app

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, mobile, angular

I have done the angular1(**ng1**) app and now I want to move the app into angular2(**ng2**). the main purpose of that is, more flexible use in mobile context.

Do I need to implement the app again or do there have anyway to migrate **ng1** into **ng2** app?

Answer (score 0):

*You should start Angular2 and build a new app.*

But if you want to still upgrade **ng1** to **ng2**, you should go through official document available at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html